# How can I adjust multiple 'where' clause in single query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which gives me previous id from the result but it contains multiple `where` clause .

```
SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.cm_id 
    FROM Contacts 
    LEFT JOIN Employee ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id) AND (Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y") 

WHERE ( CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' 
    AND CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 

WHERE Contacts.cm_id < (
    SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.cm_id 
        FROM Contacts 
        LEFT JOIN Employee ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id) AND (Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y") 
        WHERE ( CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' AND CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 
        WHERE Contacts.cm_id='77')

ORDER BY Contacts.cm_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

its giving me this `error`

```
'WHERE Contacts.cm_id='313')) ORDER BY Contact_Master.cm_id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 10
```

How can I adjust this query to avoid query break.
Please help

Comment: you can't use multiple WHERE, you should only use AND OR etc... after the WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query syntax ist wrong, the `AND` after the `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...` should be inside the `WHERE` caluse, and combine the `WHERE` caluses with `AND` instead of `WHERE` each time, normally you have only one `WHERE` for each `SELECT`.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.cm_id 
FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Employee 
     ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id) 
WHERE (Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y") 
  AND ( CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' 
  AND CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 
  AND Contacts.cm_id < 
     (SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.cm_id 
      FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Employee 
           ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id)  
      WHERE (Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y") 
        AND (CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' 
        AND CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 
        AND Contacts.cm_id='77') ORDER BY Contacts.cm_id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: It should return only only value, you are using LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Format the query make it readable
If you are using any aggregate function in where clause, use

> HAVING

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not have 2 'WHERE' statements. Change the second 'WHERE' to an 'AND' in each of the statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write multiple where clauses unless it is a sub query in another query. You can adjust your query by placing "AND" or "OR" instead of the other WHEREs according to your need.

Try below query (I am placing AND instead of WHERE, you can adjust AND according to your needs.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.cm_id FROM Contacts 
LEFT JOIN Employee ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id) AND 
(Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y") 

WHERE ( CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' AND 
CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 
AND Contacts.cm_id < (SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.cm_id FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Employee  
ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id) AND (Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y") 
AND ( CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' AND  
CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 
AND Contacts.cm_id='77') 
ORDER BY Contacts.cm_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Note: ** This query is not tested, and is just for your idea. It may / may not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the [syntax of SELECT in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) again, because your query is totally wrong.

Due to the fact I don't know the database structure and the origin task what you wanted to retrieve, I'm not sure that the result will be correct.

But getting rid of excessiveness in your query I got this:

```
SELECT MAX Contacts.cm_id as cm_id FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Employee ON (Contacts.cm_id = Employee.ei_contact_id) WHERE Employee.ei_primary_employer = "Y" AND CONCAT( Contacts.cm_fname," ", Contacts.cm_lname ) LIKE '%Recee Dawn%' AND Contacts.cm_id < 77
```

Hope you'll get what you expect.